# How can I check if something in html is set to false or true using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I have a html file and I wanna check some values in it. 
For example: data-online="false", data-channel="123breakmefree"

So I wanna check if 'data-online' is set to true or false and what channel is marked in data-channel. And if channel is something else than '123breakmefree'.

Thanks!

P.S: English is not my main language so I could not find anything on that by googling.

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried out.  We need more concrete questions to be able to help you out.

Comment: Basically something like that:"https://github.com/tanelq/project/blob/master/twitchgdaget"

Comment: But it prints -1. For some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows how to load a html string, get a tag and then the attributes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div id="my-tag" data-online="false" data-channel="123breakmefree">test text</div>'

s = BeautifulSoup(html)
tag = s.find(id='my-tag')

print tag.attrs
print tag['data-online']
print tag['data-channel']
```